# Im getting TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm totally new to python and panda framework.
Im trying to process large file set (excel) and group by using few column names.
Each file contains following columns;

```
Site Dip Time                  TankId  Product
ABC  10/09/2019 18:07:33 p.m.   1      diesel
```

.....

After implying datecolumn, when I list datatypes;
i get **Dip Time as object**. why?;

Site            object
Tank ID          int64
Product         object
Dip Time        object
dtype: object

Also i get following error; 
Why the date column is interpreted as string here? What should I do to overcome this?

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

import pandas as pd
    def read_dipsfile(writer):
        atg_path = '/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/data/dips'
        files = os.listdir(atg_path)
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        dateCols = ['Dip Time']
        for f in files:
            data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(atg_path, f), sheet_name='Tank Export', skiprows=[0], parse_dates=dateCols,
                                     infer_datetime_format =True)
            df = df.append(data)
        print(df.dtypes)

        x = df.groupby(['Site', 'Tank ID', 'Product'], as_index=False).apply(atg_aggregation)
        x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DipsSummary')


def atg_aggregation(data):
    count = data['Dip Time'].count()
    minVal = data['Dip Time'].min()
    maxVal = data['Dip Time'].max()
    tankcount = data['Tank ID'].count()
    productcount = data['Product'].count()

    agg = {
        'totalRecords': count,
        'firstSeen': minVal,
        'lastSeen': maxVal,
        'tankCount': tankcount,
        'productCount': productcount
    }
    return pd.Series(agg, index=['totalRecords', 'firstSeen', 'lastSeen', 'tankCount', 'productCount'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time is already in a 24 hour format. Why is am / pm required?

Also its the "p.m." that is making the column "object" type, even when you are using parse_dates parameter in read_excel.

Parse_dates work when "Dip Time" column doesn't have "p.m." in it.

```
 Site            Dip Time  Tank ID Product
0  ABC 2019-10-09 18:07:00        1  Diesel

df2=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\check.csv', parse_dates=datecols)

df2.dtypes
Out[14]: 
Site                object
Dip Time    datetime64[ns]
Tank ID              int64
Product             object
dtype: object
```

Code to remove "a.m/p.m" and make "Dip Time" column a datetime type.

```
  Site                 Dip Time  Tank ID Product
0  ABC  10/09/2019 18:07:33 p.m        1  Diesel

df2['Dip Time']=df2['Dip Time'].str.replace('[a-z].m', '', regex=True).str.strip()

df2
Out[34]: 
  Site             Dip Time  Tank ID Product
0  ABC  10/09/2019 18:07:33        1  Diesel

df2.dtypes
Out[35]: 
Site        object
Dip Time    object
Tank ID      int64
Product     object
dtype: object

import datetime

df2['Dip Time']=pd.to_datetime(df2['Dip Time'])

df2.dtypes
Out[38]: 
Site                object
Dip Time    datetime64[ns]
Tank ID              int64
Product             object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks ..But I get files in that format..I can not edit them locally since the amount of files are huge..can I remove p.m /a.m via python and allow panda to process?